# Which ODBC driver to use for sqlite and  Sparx Systems Enterprise Architect?

Tags: sqlite, odbc, reverse-engineering, enterprise-architect

The new Sparx Systems Enterprise Architect 9 supports now sqlite. And according to the documentation including reverse engineering.

But if one looks at the instruction to reverse engineering a DDL it is all about ODBC.

So I take it I need an ODBC driver for my sqlite database in order to reverse engineer the db schema.

Sure there are enough to be found by google but has anybody a suggestion which ODBC driver would work well for the task at hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I used http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc which worked as expected. Note that you might also need a rooted phone to download the db.